# Selecting data from 2 tables where columns are the same, query not quite right?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch data from 2 tables where the `prop_slug` and `prop_gallery_id` match. I've written the following statement only I cant seem to get it to work and keep getting an error with my syntax - can anybody see if there's a glaring mistake in my query?...

```
$listings = $db->query('
SELECT * 
  FROM listing_details 
  JOIN prop_gallery 
    ON prop_gallery.prop_gallery_id = listing_details.prop_slug 
 WHERE (listing_details.prop_slug LIKE \'prop_gallery_id\' OR prop_gallery.prop_gallery_id LIKE \'prop_slug\') 
   AND 
 WHERE listing_details.prop_mandate = 1 
 LIMIT 3')->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Can you find any examples of queries with multiple WHERE clauses? Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. For further help, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think that you have added two where clause because of which you're getting the syntax error. Try removing the where clause after and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second `WHERE`

```
$listings = $db->query('
SELECT * 
  FROM listing_details 
  JOIN prop_gallery 
    ON prop_gallery.prop_gallery_id = listing_details.prop_slug 
 WHERE (listing_details.prop_slug LIKE \'prop_gallery_id\' OR prop_gallery.prop_gallery_id LIKE \'prop_slug\') 
   AND listing_details.prop_mandate = 1 
 LIMIT 3')->fetchAll();
```